# How to find row and column names of the n-th highest values in a 2D array in Excel?

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array

I want to find the **row and column names** of the **n-th** highest values in a 2D array in Excel.
My array has a header row (the `Coins`) and a header column (the `Markets`). The data itself displays if a coin is supported on the market and if so what the approximate return of investment (`ROI`) will be in percent.

### Example

An example of the array could look like this:

| ROI | Coin A | Coin B | Coin C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Market 1 | N/A | 7.8% | 5.7% |
| Market 2 | 0.4% | 6.8% | N/A |
| Market 3 | 0.45% | 7.6% | 12.3% |

**Pay attention:** So some values are also set to `N/A` (or is there a better way to display that a market doesn't support a specific coin? I don't want to enter `0%` as it makes it harder to spot is a coin is supported by the market. I also don't want to leave that field blank because then I don't know if I already checked that market for that coin.)

### Preferred output

The output for the example table from above with `n=3` should then look like this (from high `ROI` to low):

| Coin | Market | ROI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | 3 | 12.3% |
| B | 1 | 7.8% |
| A | 3 | 0.45% |

### Requirements

Each coin must only be shown once. So, for example, `Coin B` **must not** be listed twice in the Top3 output (once for `Market 1: 7.8%` and once for `Market 3: 7.6%`)

### What I tried

So I thought about how to split up that problem into smaller parts. I think, it will come to these main parts:

- **find header/row name**

  - [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2547-excel-find-highest-value-in-a-row-and-return-column-title.html) I found something to find the column name for the highest value per row but I wasn't able to adapt it to a working solution for a 2D array
- **find max in 2D array**

  - [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-location-of-value-in-2d-array) they describe to find the max value in a 2D array but not how to find the n-th highest values
- **find n-th highest values**

  - [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/11/19/excel-formula-find-top-bottom-values/) is a good explanation on how to find the highest n values of a 1D array but not how to apply that for a 2D array
- **only include each coin once**

So I really tried to solve this myself but I struggle with adding these different parts together.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Office 365